# Can not find the tag library descriptor for [custom tags]

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I am using `SimpleTagSupport` to create custom tags. My test.jsp is located in /webapp. At the 2nd line of the jsp i have this code:

`<%@ taglib prefix="test" uri="/WEB-INF/tld/tags.tld" %>`

This should load the tags.tld in which i am specifying my custom tags like `<test:helloWorld/>`. However Eclipse tells me it is not able to find the tag library descriptor - even though my WEB-INF is located in /webapps. Full path: /webapps/WEB-INF/told/tags.tld.

How can i fix that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your TLD file has a `<uri>` element inside the root `<taglib>` element. The value of *that* element is what you specify in the `uri` attribute of `<%@ taglib %>`.

The TLD file will be read simply by being in the subfolder of `WEB-INF`. You don't have to point to it.

Comment: So you mean in my .tld file i put <uri>myTest</uri> and point to <%@ taglib prefix="test" uri="myTest" %>? Cause that is not working either...

Comment: It probably has to actually *be* a uri, e.g. `http://example.com/mytags`

Comment: And where does that "http://example.com" come from? AFAIK i only have this <uri></uri> component in my .tld file - nothing else?

Comment: It is just a value that should be globally unique, similar to an XML namespace. Make it whatever you like.